# When do you prefer equality checks over idendity checks?

Tags: javascript

I mean, in which situations and given which constraints do you really prefer (lax) equality defined by the `==` operator, rather than strict idendity defined by the `===` operator?

Sort of personal preference I know, but certainly not entirely!

So really, let's geniunely talk about the reasoned rationales and objective justifications for using either.

Comment: `if(obj.something==null)...` hits `null` and `undefined` in one shot, good for DOM properties.

Comment: From performance point-of-view, using `===` (when possible) is better because the runtime wouldn't have to convert the value.

Comment: Also, checking for strict `boolean` values: `1 == true` vs. `1 === true`

Comment: tip: don't use `==true`, it's very complicated what results. `==false` is ok though...

Comment: @dandavis I agree with you, however you might as well just go like this `if(!obj.something)` instead of `if(obj.something==null)`

Comment: rare, but possible: `new Number(3) === 3` is false, even though you might want/need it to be true.

Comment: @AndreFeijo: no: `if(!obj.something)` would miss `0`, `false`, and `""`, all legit DOM properties. `==null` is how we can tell something is "missing" instead of falsey.

Comment: @dandavis In some cases it's not a big deal.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons?rq=1) will help you!

Comment: @AndreFeijo: one way to think of it is in cases where `obj.something` is _required_, `if(obj.something)` works fine, but if `.something` is optional in value but not in presence, `if(obj.something!=null)` makes sure it's there...

Comment: @The haha wow, megathread, nice find thanks